# Display "time" of process periodically

Tags: zsh, time

A week ago, I launched simulations as follows:

```
make rebuild; time make run
```

Using the command `time` I recorded the CPU time used in each case.

A week later, the simulations finished but, much to my surprise, the time statistics were not displayed. The `make run` target was basically just:

```
python SCRIPTNAME | tee SCRIPTNAME.log
```

and in fact I see that the output corresponding to the 4 or 5 last iterations (out of 10000) were nowhere to be found. It was neither displayed on screen, nor appended to the log file)

My questions are:

1. How can that be?
2. Is it possible to make `time` display the time statistics periodically, to avoid having to rerun the whole simulations in the case I described?

Answer (score 1):

The `time` output is displayed on stderr. So if you want to capture its output in a log file, you need to redirect stderr.

But note that in `zsh` like in `ksh`, `time` is a keyword,

```
time cmd 2>&1 |  tee log
```

Actually *times* `cmd 2>&1 | tee log` (and both `cmd` and `tee`). If you want to time `cmd` only and redirect both the stdout and stderr of `cmd` and the `time` output to the pipe to `tee`, you'd need:

```
{ time cmd; } 2>&1 | tee log
```

As to the periodic retrieval, I don't thing that's possible. That's something that's accounted by the kernel and made available to the parent process upon termination after the parent has *wait()ed* for its child (using `getrusage()`).

Also note that the usage of grand-children that are not waited for by their parent is not accounted even if they have died by the time `time` reports the usage (`init` will actually be accounting for them).

A process can get its *own* usage information (see for instance the output of `time` alone in `zsh`), but again for the `children` part, it would only get incremented when your direct children die and report their usage, so even if you started `make` in background and ran `time` periodically, the `children` part would not get incremented for each child of `make` terminating. `make` (the kernel on behalf of `make`) would be accounting for the usage of those children, and that cumulative usage would only be made available to `zsh` when `make` returns.

If you're only interested in CPU time, and not the other information tracked by `getrusage()` and reported by `time` once you change `$TIMEFMT`, on Linux, [you could get the information from `/proc/pid/stat` and some summary from `ps`](/a/132081), but again the *children usage* for a given process will only include the cumulative usage of the terminated direct children.

Something like:

```
time cmd &
perl -MPOSIX -l -0777 -e '
  while (<STDIN>) {
    @f = /\(.*\)|\S+/gs;
    printf "%s %s cutime: %.2f cstime: %.2f\n",
      strftime("%T",localtime), $f[1],
      map {$_/POSIX::sysconf( &POSIX::_SC_CLK_TCK )}@f[15,16];
    sleep 1;
    seek STDIN,0,0;
  }' < /proc/$!/stat
```

Where you'll see the `cutime` (cumulative user time) and `cstime` (system) incrementing only when each of the direct children of the process that executed `cmd` dies and `cmd` has *waited* for them.

Example output with `zsh -c 'repeat 5 {head -c200M  /dev/zero | pixz > /dev/null}'` as the *`cmd`*:

```
15:19:32 (zsh) cutime: 0.00 cstime: 0.00
15:19:33 (zsh) cutime: 0.00 cstime: 0.00
15:19:34 (zsh) cutime: 0.05 cstime: 0.25
15:19:35 (zsh) cutime: 0.05 cstime: 0.25
15:19:36 (zsh) cutime: 19.21 cstime: 1.04
15:19:37 (zsh) cutime: 19.21 cstime: 1.04
15:19:38 (zsh) cutime: 19.21 cstime: 1.04
15:19:39 (zsh) cutime: 19.26 cstime: 1.31
15:19:40 (zsh) cutime: 37.94 cstime: 2.05
15:19:41 (zsh) cutime: 37.94 cstime: 2.05
15:19:42 (zsh) cutime: 37.97 cstime: 2.36
15:19:43 (zsh) cutime: 37.97 cstime: 2.36
15:19:44 (zsh) cutime: 57.17 cstime: 3.07
15:19:45 (zsh) cutime: 57.17 cstime: 3.07
15:19:46 (zsh) cutime: 57.22 cstime: 3.36
15:19:47 (zsh) cutime: 76.06 cstime: 4.10
15:19:48 (zsh) cutime: 76.06 cstime: 4.10
15:19:49 (zsh) cutime: 76.06 cstime: 4.10
15:19:50 (zsh) cutime: 76.08 cstime: 4.42
```

Where you see the times being incremented in bulk (when the `head` and `pigz` processes die).

Comment: In fact I was trying to explain that the end of stdout wasn't appended to the log file, as if `tee` truncates the output to the last full page, or something like that.